# iOS app for tracking groceries and other essentials at home

Tags: ios, productivity

I am looking for an app to track my groceries and other essentials like medications, pet food, self-care and cleaning essentials.

What else I want is that the app notifies me when something is expiring or finishing. Also, it would be nice that the app allows to put goods in categories and it should also has some good global search. Also, I would love that I could tell in the app where I bought this or that product, like in which store, no need to have an exact address, just a hint. This would help me to plan my next shopping trip.

The app should be for iOS and preferably gratis, but I don't mind to pay for something worthful as well.

Comment: If you shop on Amazon, it has those little smart button thingies ... [Dash](https://www.amazon.com/b/?node=10667898011&ref=sxts_snpl_3_2_840a44ff-2a11-4b03-955b-51d645f3d28e&qid=1535016973&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=840a44ff-2a11-4b03-955b-51d645f3d28e&pf_rd_r=J9JRHPVGN2Y0A3PK4HZ0&pd_rd_wg=jA1O8&pf_rd_s=desktop-signpost&pf_rd_t=301&pd_rd_w=dc4km&pf_rd_i=dash&pd_rd_r=3864060a-4723-4c46-89c7-6dd15cc1d3ad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve been using PikyPak (‎https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pikypak/id1292018000) for several months so far and I can only say that I LOVE it.

First of all, the user interface is just great. It’s simple, yet powerful. Secondly, I love the notifications. It notifies me whenever something is expiring or finishing. It also doesn’t let me forget to update the stuff in the app when I for example spend my groceries in my fridge. The other thing I like in the app is that when you just open it you can see from the first glance what you have and what is going to finish or expire soon. That helps me to plan my next shopping trip.

I found that I can use this app not only for my fridge and pantry, but also to track my cleaning and self-care essentials as well as medicines and pets food. PikyPak allows to categories the items and provides a very powerful search over all your items in the app, which is very cool when you have a long list of stuff and want to just quickly find a needed item.

All in all, I highly recommend this app instead of using paper sheets. Go green! :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. So far, I really like this app.